# VMware Player + Debian: No internet connection with network nat

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, vmware, nat

I don't know what I did or what changed but about an hour ago I lost internet connection on my VMware Player with latest Debian installed. I already restarted Host and Client, reinstalled VMware-Tools, removed and added a virtual network adapter with NAT enabled, but all that didn't change anything.

I took a look at `VMware Network Adapter VMnet1` and `VMware Network Adapter VMnet8` and they both tell me that they don't have network access:

[image]

Could this possibly be the root of the problem?

Edit: This is the Virtual Network Editor:

[image]

**Edit 2: I downloaded the latest 14.1.1-version of VMware Player and upgraded to this latest version - now network is working again.**

Comment: Type `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` then `nmcli networking on` on terminal.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you use the connection troubleshooter in the VM on VMnet8? VMnet1 here appears to be configured only to allow the VMs to communicate with each other; VMnet8 appears to be the connection that gets you to the Internet. I'm under the impression your guest just needs to request a new IP address.

Comment: Do you mean if I use the windows troubleshooter for VMnet8? I use Debian as a Guest-System on Windows 10.
Windows just tells me that the problem couldn't be identified.
`I'm under the impression your guest just needs to request a new IP address.` Debian doesn't see any available connections, I doubt that it's possible to request a new IP if no connection is established.

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: I don't see an update? :(

Answer (score 0):

Open VmWare Virtual Network Editor and reconfigure vmnets

Comment: I appended a screenshot of the Virtual Network Editor. What should I do?